# How to trigger ngModelChange with a button in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, forms, checkbox

I use `*ngFor` to populate my table.

```
<tr *ngFor= "stu in students">
<td>{{stu.name}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" ngModel="isChecked" 
(ngModelChange)="addID(stu.id)</td>
</tr>
```

Then I have a button outside the table.

```
<button (click)="selectAllID()">select all</button>
```

Then I have my component as:

```ts
studentID=[];
isChecked=false;

addID(id:number){
this.student.push (id);
//I do other thing with id
}

selectAllID (){
 If (this.isChecked)
     this isChecked = false;
  else this isChecked = true
}
```

The problem is:

if I check individual checkbox, the `addID()` function is executed. But if I click on the select all button, the checkboxes get selected. But the `addID()` function is not called.

How can I trigger the `ngModelChange` function when I use the select all button so I get all selected `id`'s

Comment: Use brackets on ngModel as [ngModel]="isChecked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone. i finally resolved the issue. This is what i did:

1. I used the selectAll() function to automatically load all id's (this id i get from the source loading my tables) to an array. and 
   i set the value of isChecked to true or false.

Answer (score 2):

You have only one way binding of the input control with `ngModelChange` directive. But to update the view you should bind the control to `ngModel`.

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isChecked" 
(ngModelChange)="addID(stu.id)">
```

Comment: Thank you. i have added the [ ]. the checkbox button get checked but the [ngModelChange] doesn't get fired.

Comment: it's fired when you change the value of the `ngModel`.